# BizTalk Flatfile schema wizard multiple repeating records with optional records

Tags: schema, biztalk, flat-file

**BizTalk Flat File Schema Wizard:**

I have the following sample file with IN2 and RS2 occurring only in some instances i.e., optional. I tried by creating a record and grouping all the nodes under it, but no luck. Please help.

PAT614604002     20150823HEBI      KAREN               SSALINASGONZALEZ                                    19901028FS614604002
EMP614604002     2015082399999                                            AMAX AUTO INSURANCE
GAR614604002     20150823614604002           KAREN               SSALINASGONZALEZ                     112 SUNNYVALE TER
ADR614604002     20150823112 SUNNYVALE TER                                           HURST               TX760534033
IN1614604002     20150823A50                   614604002      01    ZGP820124451             107163
IN2614604002     20150823P01                   614604002      01    523108441
RS1614604002     20150823614604002           KAREN                SALINAS                             112 SUNNYVALE TER
RS2614604002     20150823614604002           KAREN               FGONZALEZ                            112 SUNNYVALE TER
PAT464711615     20150823HEBI      PATRICE             ATAVE                                               19720731FM464711615
EMP464711615     2015082300017                                            AT AND T
GAR464711615     20150823464711615           PATRICE             ATAVE                                7917 GREEN VALLEY DR
ADR464711615     201508237917 GREEN VALLEY DR                                        N RICHLND HLS       TX761827314
IN1464711615     20150823F85                   464711615      01    973985126                503777
RS1464711615     20150823464711615           PATRICE              TAVE                                7917 GREEN VALLEY DR

PAT, EMP, GAR, ADR, IN2, RS1, RS2 are the tag identifiers. First 8 lines form one record and next 6 lines form another record. IN2 and RS2 should be optional.

As my schema is not able to fit in the space limit provided, I have uploaded the schema and other details of my issue at

http://1drv.ms/1KQH2WK

Any Biztalk experts please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  Normally we consider questions good that 1) provide a minimally complete example of a problem 2) some attempt to solve it 3) what you're getting stuck with.  As is, your question would be tough to answer without either writing code for you or just pointing you to documentation/a tutorial.  I'd recommend searching Google for "Biztalk Flat file tag", posting your attempted schema, and a more specific question about what specific error you're seeing.

Comment: My schema is very long and it does not fit in the space provided. Even with a trimmed down version.

Comment: Try to isolate the part that isn't working into a reproducible problem.  You may find you solve your own question this way, but at least you could share something that answerers could reproduce independently and help you with.

Comment: Dan, I have included all the details of the issue in the link mentioned.

Comment: @TonupunuriP  The question needs to stand on it's own without links to external resources, as eventually external links can become invalid and then the question loses it's usefulness for other facing a similar problem.  Can't you give a simple example of what you are trying to achieve with a smaller schema?

Answer (score 0):

I find the flat wizard rather clunky and quite often do it by hand instead.

Start of by creating a schema that just consumes each of the lines.

e.g.

```
Root
  Record (repeating)
    Line
```

Then slowly add things in order from the file

```
Root
  PAT (tag: PAT)
    Field1
    Field2
  Record (repeating)
    Line
```

Continue until you have the first set of records setting the optional ones to min occurs 0 and max occurs 1.

```
Root
  PAT
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  EMP
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  GAR
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  ADR 
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  IN2 
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  RS1 
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  RS2
    Field1
    Field2
    ...
  Record (repeating)
    Line
```

Then add a repeating Group and move your set off records under that.